# How to call method keys in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning about Tkinter at the moment. To get more information about the methods I read the pydocs.

Problem is when I call:

```
>>>help(Text.configure)
```

I get :

```
configure(self, cnf=None, **kw)
Configure resources of a widget.

The values for resources are specified as keyword
arguments. To get an overview about
the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.
```

So how would I call or list all the method keys?

I've tried:

```
>>>Text.configure.keys()
```

and

```
>>>Text.configure().keys()
```

But of course they do not work because it's a function not a dictionary.

Comment: Perhaps try `Text().keys()`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani that's a `TypeError`; it's an instance method, not a class method

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I was guessing but I see you've already answered.

Comment: Also just realised that `>>>help(Text)` shows them as well, just that they are named differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`keys` is an instance method of all `Widget` sub-classes, you can access it as follows:

```
>>> from Tkinter import Text
>>> help(Text.keys)
Help on method keys in module Tkinter:

keys(self) unbound Tkinter.Text method
    Return a list of all resource names of this widget.

>>> Text().keys()
['autoseparators', 'background', 'bd', 'bg', 'blockcursor', 'borderwidth', 'cursor', 
 'endline', 'exportselection', 'fg', 'font', 'foreground', 'height', 'highlightbackground',
 'highlightcolor', 'highlightthickness', 'inactiveselectbackground', 'insertbackground',
 'insertborderwidth', 'insertofftime', 'insertontime', 'insertwidth', 'maxundo', 'padx',
 'pady', 'relief', 'selectbackground', 'selectborderwidth', 'selectforeground', 'setgrid',
 'spacing1', 'spacing2', 'spacing3', 'startline', 'state', 'tabs', 'tabstyle', 'takefocus',
 'undo', 'width', 'wrap', 'xscrollcommand', 'yscrollcommand']
```

Comment: So this would work only with Tkinter, right? So if function or method accepts **kw, how could I check what they are? Or keys method is a convention of some sort?

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij yes, only with Tkinter (as far as I'm aware). In the general case, follow whatever guidance is provided in the documentation for the function/method you're using.